# Show Buy signal if volume is greater than volume20 and candle closes on ema 9

Tags: pine-script

I found a script (thanks to user SafetyHammer) that shows a buy signal if volume is greater than volume20. I want to consider also the condition that the signal only shows up if the candle closes on ema 9.

```
    //@version=4

study(title="Volume & SMA", overlay=false, format=format.volume)

length          = input(20,"Long MA Length", type=input.integer)
color           = close > open ? color.new(color.green,50) : color.new(color.red,50)
sma             = sma(volume, length)
buy             = close > open and crossover(volume,sma)
plot(volume, title="volume", style=plot.style_columns, color= color, histbase=0)
plot(sma, title = "Long MA", color = color.red)
plotshape(buy,title = "CrossUp indicator", location = location.top, style=shape.triangleup, text="Buy", color = color.new(color.green,50))
```

When looking at https://imgshare.io/images/2021/10/13/2021-10-13-11_24_41-Windowd67797464ddd29a7.png you can see that there is no "buy" signal in the yellow frame. Reason as far as I understand is that it did not cross in the yellow. The volume before the yellow box is already above the avg vol so there is no crossingover.

How do I need to change the condition so I could get a buy signal 1.) everytime the vol20 is greater than volume and 2.) the green candle closes on the ema9? Looking at my screenshot it would  be the second green candle with the red arrow below.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
ema9 = ema(close, 9)
closed_over_ema9 = open < ema9 and close > ema9
buy = close > open and volume > sma and closed_over_ema9
```